# NodeJS Commander structured subcommands

Tags: node.js, node-commander

I am new to commander and I am trying to achieve a command tree like this:

```
|- build
|    |- browser (+ options)
|    |- cordova (+ options)
|    |- no subcommands, just options
|- config
|    |- create (+ options)
```

Is it possible to split these commands up into multiple files, for example somewhat like this:

Central File:

```js
const program = new commander.Command();
program.command('build').description(...);
program.command('config').description(...);
```

File for build command:

```
program.command('browser').description(...);
program.command('cordova').description(...);
program.option(...);
```

File for config command:

```
program.command('create').description(...);
```

I know of the Git-Style subcommands, but these seem to require executable files (I only have regular JS files)

Answer (score 12):

There is an example in their documentation here:

```
const commander = require('commander');
const program = new commander.Command();
const brew = program.command('brew');
brew
  .command('tea')
  .action(() => {
    console.log('brew tea');
  });
brew
  .command('coffee')
  .action(() => {
    console.log('brew coffee');
  });
```

Example output:

```
$ node nestedCommands.js brew tea
brew tea
```

https://github.com/tj/commander.js/blob/master/examples/nestedCommands.js

Answer (score 9):

There is explicit support in Commander for standalone subcommand "executable" files with the `.js` file extension, without needing to set file permissions etc to make it directly executable on command line.

pm.js

```
const commander = require('commander');
const program = new commander.Command();
program
  .command('build', 'build description')
  .command('config', 'config description')
  .parse(process.argv);
```

pm-config.js

```
const commander = require('commander');
const program = new commander.Command();
program
  .command('create')
  .description('create description')
  .action(() => {
    console.log('Called create');
  });
program.parse(process.argv);
```

```
$ node pm.js config create
Called create
```

Comment: If I read the GitHub issues of commander correctly, there may have been an update regarding this functionality in commander5.0

Comment: From Commander v5 you can have nested commands using just action handlers in a single program. Previously more than one layer of subcommands needed stand-alone executables.

Comment: Subcommands can also be created and exported from their own files, and added to the parent command using `.addCommand()`.